# Should my swap size be zero or am I misunderstanding the output?

Tags: 14.04, swap, tomcat7

We are running an Amazon EC2 R3 instance so has 30G of memory available. We are running 5 Apache Tomcats (version 7). According to *lsb_release -a* the version of Ubuntu is: Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS

Tomcats keep terminating on this machine from unknown conditions. This machine is more than adequate to run many Tomcats and after a single Tomcat termination, running *free -h* shows at least 10G available.

When I run the command cat/proc/swaps the following is displayed:

```
cat /proc/swaps
Filename                                Type            Size    Used    Priority
```

Does this mean that no swap partition is in place? Running the swapon command shows the same output:

```
swapon -s
Filename                                Type            Size    Used    Priority
```

Running the top command shows:

```
Swap:        0 total,        0 used,        0 free.
```

So do these results show that no swap is available for when processes need it or does it show no swap is currently being used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as there is free memory available, the system will never use swap. In fact, swapping should be avoided in a system as possible...

On the other hand, in your case, it seems that you don't have a swap partition. Otherwise you should see something like this:

```
$ swapon -s 
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/dev/sdb1                               partition   1952764 0   -1
```

Comment: Agree about avoiding swapping, but I am trying to determine why the "watchdog" is terminating my Tomcats (assuming that is what is happening).  So does the output above show that I have no swap space allocated or no swap space is being used or do I need to run another process to find out my swap size?

Comment: Try `sudo fdisk -l` to see your partitions

Comment: This results in: `Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
    /dev/xvda1   *       16065    16771859     8377897+  83  Linux`
so this indicates no swap partition. Thank you for clearing that up.

Answer (score 0):

If I were You , I'd use multiple smaller EC2 Instances (t2 mini-micro) each for dedicated tomcat with dedicated hostings usin an EBL( Elastic Load Balancer) & ASG (auto scaling groups). 
It will give a  more robust package as far as multiple apache are under consideration and will be more cost efficient.